# Should I scale my data before a Cartesian-to-spherical conversion?

Tags: classification, data-transformation, multi-class, feature-scaling, one-class

If I have three features, should I scale them before converting them to a spherical coordinate system?

I have been working on a ternary classification problem. My data is high-dimensional, so I've been using one-class techniques such as SVM with different kernels, local outlier factor, and linear discriminant analysis to extract new features within the training splits; this approach appears to be working well.

I noticed some radial patterns in visualizing these features so I decided to treat the trios of per-class features as Cartesian coordinates and converted them to spherical coordinates as new features. Before conversion, the features were on vastly different scales, so I tried a couple of different scaling techniques such as Yeo-Johnson power transform, standard scaling, or quantile transform before obtaining the spherical coordinates. Downstream, there is some more feature engineering and one more scaling step before the classifier is trained.

Adding the spherical features appears to boost performance, but I haven't noticed a big difference between the choice of pre-spherical scaling and saw some evidence in tree-based feature importance to suggest that omitting scaling before the spherical transformation might even yield the best performance.

Is there any theoretical motivation to scale or not to scale before performing such a Cartesian-to-spherical transformation? If so, may I safely assume it applies to 2D conversions (polar coordinates) as well?

Comment: Use whatever variables created the "radial patterns," because differential scaling otherwise will destroy those patterns.  Alternatively, why make this (very complex) conversion in the first place?  Why not just include the radial distance as one more feature?

Comment: @whuber thank you for your comment. I had just read a paper where features from both Cartesian and polar coordinate systems were combined for better classification performance and thought I'd try it. What do you mean by the radial distance? Are you referring to the rho coordinate rather than the angle (phi/theta) coordinates?

Comment: Yes: $\rho$ is just the radial distance (from the origin).

Comment: @whuber I actually am considering discarding the rho coordinates while preserving the theta/phi. The classes look more like spokes radiating out of the origin rather than concentric circles, if that makes sense; so angle around the origin is more informative than the distance from it.

Comment: There's a disconnect here: how are these 2D points related to your "high-dimensional" data?

Comment: @whuber The 2D points would be linear discriminant analysis components of different subsets of the full feature set (i.e., two components each for ternary classification). The 3D points would be one-class scores (e.g. local outlier factor) of those subsets. I have 2048 features before any of these manipulations are performed. Where is the disconnect? [Thanks for getting back to me. Happy holidays~]